# Why is searching for strings in a text file using powershell 4.0 get ignored if the strings are placed in a sequence vs a different sequence?

Tags: powershell, select-string

Code that works because results.txt includes all instances of WORD_2, PHRASE2, WORD, and PHRASE:

```
$output_file = ‘results.txt’
$listtomatch = @("WORD_2", "PHRASE2","WORD",  "PHRASE") 
select-string -Path filetosearchin.txt -Pattern $listtomatch -CaseSensitive | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Code that doesn't work because it returns only all instances of WORD and PHRASE but doesn't return WORD_2 nor PHRASE2:

```
$output_file = ‘results.txt’
$listtomatch = @("WORD", "PHRASE","WORD_2",  "PHRASE2") 
select-string -Path filetosearchin.txt -Pattern $listtomatch -CaseSensitive | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

is the sequence of the strings interferring in the way these are fed into select-string giving a different outcome?

I had expected both codes above to give the same result: all instances of all strings: WORD_2, PHRASE2, WORD, and PHRASE

Comment: because it is performing a RegEx match, which isn't really designed for an array like that. Try joining your array with pipes, that should work for you. `$listtomatch = 'WORD_2|PHRASE2|WORD|PHRASE'` or since it is regex, more simply `$listtomatch = 'WORD(?:_2)?|PHRASE2?'` since it's pattern matching.

Comment: The order in the pattern array matters. If the first element of the array matches, the remainder of the array will not match on that line. In your second batch of code, if a line matches WORD, PHRASE will never be matched on that line. Since WORD will always match WORD_2 but not vice versa, you are going to get different results between the two code samples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let PowerShell create the [alternations(|)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and also include the `-AllMatches` parameter:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\07\31\SO_57297393.ps1
$listtomatch = @("WORD_2","PHRASE2","WORD","PHRASE") 

Select-String -Path filetosearchin.txt -Pattern ($listtomatch -join '|') -CaseSensitive -AllMatches| 
   % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

With an input file:

```
> Get-Content .\filetosearchin.txt
1:"WORD_2","PHRASE2","WORD","PHRASE"
2:"PHRASE2","WORD","PHRASE","WORD_2"
3:"WORD","PHRASE","WORD_2","PHRASE2"
4:"PHRASE","WORD_2","PHRASE2","WORD"
```

The script yields:

```
> .\SO_57297393.ps1
WORD_2
PHRASE2
WORD
PHRASE
PHRASE2
WORD
PHRASE
WORD_2
WORD
PHRASE
WORD_2
PHRASE2
PHRASE
WORD_2
PHRASE2
WORD
```